# Perforce error - cannot submit from non-stream client

Tags: perforce

Coming from GIT and SVN background, I've set up my P4V in windows, managed to get the content of my repository into my local folder (somehow), but once I made modification and create new files in my local folder, I cant submit it back to Perforce. It gives error:

//depot/main/p4config.txt - warning: cannot submit from non-stream client
No files to submit.
Submit failed -- fix problems above then use 'p4 submit -c 6'.

My depot hierarchy:

```
C:\Perforce\kernelpanic\main>p4 client -S //depot/main -o
# A Perforce Client Specification.
#
#  Client:      The client name.
#  Update:      The date this specification was last modified.
#  Access:      The date this client was last used in any way.
#  Owner:       The user who created this client.
#  Host:        If set, restricts access to the named host.
#  Description: A short description of the client (optional).
#  Root:        The base directory of the client workspace.
#  AltRoots:    Up to two alternate client workspace roots.
#  Options:     Client options:
#                      [no]allwrite [no]clobber [no]compress
#                      [un]locked [no]modtime [no]rmdir
#  SubmitOptions:
#                      submitunchanged/submitunchanged+reopen
#                      revertunchanged/revertunchanged+reopen
#                      leaveunchanged/leaveunchanged+reopen
#  LineEnd:     Text file line endings on client: local/unix/mac/win/share.
#  ServerID:    If set, restricts access to the named server.
#  View:        Lines to map depot files into the client workspace.
#  Stream:      The stream to which this client's view will be dedicated.
#               (Files in stream paths can be submitted only by dedicated
#               stream clients.) When this optional field is set, the
#               View field will be automatically replaced by a stream
#               view as the client spec is saved.
#
# Use 'p4 help client' to see more about client views and options.

Client: kernelpanic

Update: 2012/10/04 15:35:16

Access: 2012/10/04 15:59:39

Owner:  me.kernelpanic

Host:   kernelpanic

Description:
        Created by me.kernelpanic.

Root:   C:/Perforce/kernelpanic

Options:        noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir

SubmitOptions:  submitunchanged

LineEnd:        local

View:
        //depot/... //kernelpanic/...
        //depot/main/doc/... //kernelpanic/main/doc/...
        //depot/* //kernelpanic/*
        //depot/main/* //kernelpanic/main/*
```

If possible, I'd like to add the files in C:\Perforce\kernelpanic\main\src as well...
Please help, I can't understand Perforce. I've tried doing a check out both before or after making modification, but both ways also failed to submit the change to server. I'd love to stick to GIT but our client is using Perforce so we have to play nice with them. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: How are you trying to submit? From P4V or the command line? Where are your files locally? It looks like there are no files in the changelist you are trying to submit.

Comment: By the way, Perforce has just released 'Git Fusion', a new product that lets you clone a git repo for working on files stored in a Perforce server. And there's also git-p4. Either of these might let you stick with git, at least at your end.

Comment: @ChrisF: I've tried both P4V and command line, both doesn't work. My problem is like the answer provided by user1054341. Sadly, I don't understand perforce and unable to figure things out

Comment: @user1054341 That doesn't seem to help.  I'm facing this problem, and `git p4 submit` failed just as well (`p4_system(["sync"] + list(options) + [wildcard_encode(f)])` resulting in `CalledProcessError`).

Answer (score 80, accepted):

It's possible that P4V has guided you to create a stream depot and a mainline, but has somehow created a non-stream workspace for you. From what I've heard, that's likely to happen for first-time P4V users due to something in the setup.

To see if that's the problem, go to Connection/Edit Workspace and look in the 'Stream' field. Is it empty? If so, use Browse to select the stream. This will turn your current workspace into a stream workspace.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This solve the problems, now all my changelists can be submitted! I really don't know about these workspace and stream thingy and have no idea to troubleshoot... Google also provide very little help.. really really appreciate your help..

Comment: This is almost another question, but WHY does this happen to first time users so much? I actually hate this feature. I've used P4 for years without streams, and streams have caused nothing but problems (most minor like this, but some major ones)

Comment: Good thing this still works over 10 years later. Insane. Thank you! my Team thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to work with the command-line, you can add a stream to your client as follows:

Show available streams:

```sh
$ p4 streams
Stream //stream/...1
Stream //stream/...2
Stream //stream/...3
…
```

Check your current client config:

```sh
$ p4 client -o
...
```

In my case, there was no stream mentioned there.  Then edit the client config:

```sh
$ p4 client
```

and add:

```
Stream: //stream/...1
```

Check that it worked by rerunning `p4 client -o`.

Now retry `p4 submit`.