# How to use streams with custom view mapping in with Perforce and Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, perforce

I'm using Perforce running in a Jenkins Pipeline. I checkout from Perforce with this:

```
          checkout scm: [
                $class: 'PerforceScm', 
                credential: 'me', 
                populate: [
                    $class: 'AutoCleanImpl', 
                    delete: true, 
                    modtime: false, 
                    pin: '', 
                    quiet: true, 
                    replace: true
                ], 
                workspace: [
                    $class: 'ManualWorkspaceImpl', 
                    charset: 'utf8', 
                    name: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}', 
                    pinHost: false, 
                    spec: [
                      allwrite: true, 
                      clobber: false, 
                      compress: false, 
                      line: 'LOCAL', 
                      locked: false, 
                      modtime: false, 
                      rmdir: false, 
                      streamName: '',
                      view: '''//depot/main/... //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}/assets/...
                               -//depot/main/pre_ar_archive/... //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}/assets/pre_ar_archive/...
                               -//depot/main/tools/... //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}/assets/tools/...'''
                    ]
                ]
            ]
```

I use a custom mapping to locate the files I need at a specific folder and exclude folders I do not need.

Once checked out, my build stage will run a python script to process the assets. This script uses p4python. Once done, it will submit. However, when I submit, I get this error:

"No files to submit.\n Submit failed -- fix problems above then use 'p4 submit -c 1234'"

The problem is this:

[Perforce error - cannot submit from non-stream client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731649/perforce-error-cannot-submit-from-non-stream-client)

If I run `p4 client`, I can see that I don't have a Stream defined. If I modify my checkout to define a 'streamName', then I find that it will use a default view which is essentially

`//depot/main/... //jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}/...`

Thus I lose my mapping.

Is there any work around for this?

One thing I could do is just use p4v to create the client I need, but then that seems to force me to just invoke all of my perforce commands that the plugin is otherwise doing.

I have tried to use p4 client to map it, but when I do, it also changes the view. p4 documentation indicates that it will do this (use a default view).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that `//depot/main` is a stream (although there are a lot of things about this question that make no sense if it's a stream, like why you ever tried to create a manual client view in the first place if your main depot is a stream depot).  If it's not, there's some entirely other problem going on here, which is something along the lines of your Jenkins client having files checked out that are in some unrelated stream and outside your client view (which would point at some misconfiguration on the Jenkins side, or a really bad bug in your script, or a bad trigger on the server, or something).

---

With streams you construct a view in the form of a stream spec that can then be shared across multiple clients.  So your view:

```
//depot/main/... //client/assets/...
-//depot/main/pre_ar_archive/... //client/assets/pre_ar_archive/...
-//depot/main/tools/... //client/assets/tools/...
```

should be represented as a stream that looks something like this:

```
Stream: //depot/main-jenkins
Parent: //depot/main
Type: virtual
Paths:
    share ...
    exclude pre_ar_archive/...
    exclude tools/...
Remapped:
    ... assets/...
```

Then you'd configure your Jenkins client like this (I think; I don't really know anything about the Jenkins configuration):

```
            workspace: [
                $class: 'StreamWorkspaceImpl', 
                charset: 'utf8', 
                name: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}', 
                pinHost: false, 
                spec: [
                  allwrite: true, 
                  clobber: false, 
                  compress: false, 
                  line: 'LOCAL', 
                  locked: false, 
                  modtime: false, 
                  rmdir: false, 
                  streamName: '//depot/main-jenkins'
                ]
            ]
```

Specifying the `//depot/main-jenkins` stream gives you the automatically generated view for that stream.

Comment: thanks for the reply. And I get what you mean. I cannot say I'm great at using Perforce, although I'd say your response is pretty insightful. Yes, //depot/main is a existing stream. And it's clear from what you are saying that I need to create a custom stream for this. Let me do try this out...

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this would mean that I have to merge streams? I ideally want the files to be treated as the same file set. This is a build system that processes art assets. So there are folders that represent inbound and folders that represent outbound files (processed).

Comment: No, this is exactly what a virtual stream is for (the "type: Virtual" in my answer is very important) -- rather than branching and merging from the parent stream, the child stream just references the parent's files with its own set of mappings.  Literally all you should need to do is what I outlined.  :)  Try creating the stream first and then making a client of that stream from the command line so you can play around with how it works.

Comment: Ahh, got it. My apologies as I missed that part. Super helpful. Thanks for teaching me more about streams. I also viewed this which was helpful. https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/using-virtual-streams

Comment: The one thing odd here is that exclude doesn't seem to work in this context. The view produced does look correct.  The remap works. but effectively despite the mapping that shows up, it ends up syncing everything

Comment: The weird thing is p4 does not prevent user from creating a non-stream workspace with a view of stream files but prevents submitting.

Comment: Also it seems remapping folder to the root folder of virtual stream is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

Okay adding on to this. This does work. The workspace class needs to be `StreamWorkspaceImpl`

```
           checkout scm: [
                $class: 'PerforceScm', 
                credential: 'me', 
                populate: [
                    $class: 'AutoCleanImpl', 
                    delete: true, 
                    modtime: false, 
                    pin: '', 
                    quiet: true, 
                    replace: true
                ], 
                workspace: [
                    $class: 'StreamWorkspaceImpl', 
                    charset: 'utf8', 
                    format: 'jenkins-${NODE_NAME}-${JOB_NAME}', 
                    pinHost: false, 
                    streamName: '//depot/main-jenkins-test'
                ]
            ]
```

The stream spec that Sam Stafford listed above works.